# trying to copy data from 1 listbox to another on a different form

Tags: vb.net

I am having problems trying to copy data from one list box to another using multiple forms an a module for the global variables and arrays. At this point it is telling me that when I select and item form a secondary listbox and try sending it to my main list box it says that I am outside the bounds of the array. I have tried about every different method of doing this and Have not come up with the solution yet. I know it is probably something obvious that just hasn't hit me yet.

This is how I initiate my array to populate my secondary listbox with

```
Public mp3Albums() As String = {" Tres Hombres ZZ TOP ", " Fandango!   ZZ TOP ", " Soul Kiss Tom Duda ", " Instrumental Telepathy Tom Duda ", " Dark Side of the Moon  Pink Floyd ", " Seventh Sojourn  Moody Blues ", " In Search of the lost Chord  Moody Blues "}
```

the list box in my main form is called  lstShoppingCart

This is how I populate and the button click action to try to copy the data to my main listbox. Ignore the call for the 2nd set of data trying to be copied since if I cannot copy just one then I have no business trying to copy 2 sets for a title and a price. unless it's simpler than i thought

```
Dim frmMain As New MainForm
frmMain.lstShoppingCart.Items.Add("A" & lstVinylAlbum.SelectedIndex & ": " & lstVinylAlbum.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

Comment: What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: I have a guess, but first, try to debug it by inserting "MsgBox lstVinylAlbum.SelectedItems.Count" before the Dim frmMain statement.  Run it and let me know what the msgbox pops up.

Answer (score 1):

Start off with a small class representing an item in a list box:

```
Public Class ListItem

    Private _key As String = String.Empty
    Private _value As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As String)

        _key = key
        _value = value

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Key() As String
        Get
            Return _key
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
    End Property

    ' Prevents the object type from displaying in the list box.
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String

        Return _value

    End Function

End Class
```

Now, let's assume two ListBox objects on one form (lstLeft and lstRight), with two Buttons - one to move an item right and one to move an item left:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        InitData()

    End Sub

    Private Sub InitData()

        With lstLeft.Items

            .Add(New ListItem("1", "Tres Hombres ZZ TOP"))
            .Add(New ListItem("2", "Fandango! ZZ TOP"))
            .Add(New ListItem("3", "Soul Kiss Tom Duda"))
            .Add(New ListItem("4", "Instrumental Telepathy Tom Duda"))

        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMoveRight_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMoveRight.Click

        If lstLeft.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim selectedItem As ListItem = DirectCast(lstLeft.SelectedItem, ListItem)

            lstRight.Items.Add(selectedItem)
            lstLeft.Items.Remove(selectedItem)

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMoveLeft_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMoveLeft.Click

        If lstRight.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim selectedItem As ListItem = DirectCast(lstRight.SelectedItem, ListItem)

            lstLeft.Items.Add(selectedItem)
            lstRight.Items.Remove(selectedItem)

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

What this is doing is just adding a reference to the selected ListItem object to the "other" ListBox, and removing the reference to the selected ListItem obect from the current ListBox. If you want to do this between two separate forms, each form will need a `Public Property AddToList(item As ListItem)` function. First, call the function on the opposite form to add to that form's ListBox, and then remove the ListItem object from the current form.

Comment: Now thats some help I can work with. Thanks a ton. Im gonna study this for a few and try to impliment all this without looking for practice purposes and Ill get back to you and see if there are any parts of my code that might be off standard that I might need to work on. The semester is over but Im bound and determined to correct my mistakes. Thanks again